# React-Table compilation error element type invalid

Tags: reactable

I am learning react and trying to make the code work, that is using react-table and functional component. The example code fetches list of git-hub repos based on the search keyword entered and displays the list using react-table

There are two issues

1. compilation fails for below with error that the file cannot be found
   import 'react-table/react-table.css';
2. If I comment the line above and run npm start, it fails with the error below

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import 'react-table/react-table.css';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'full_name'
  }, {
    Header: 'URL',
    accessor: 'html_url'
  }, {
    Header: 'Owner',
    accessor: 'owner.login'
  }]

  const fetchData = () => {
    console.log(keyword);
    const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${keyword}`;
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
      setData(responseData.items);
    })
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setKeyword(e.target.value);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={fetchData} value={keyword} > fetch</button>
      <ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The issue is because I was using React-table v7 with code from react-table v6

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because I was using React-table v7 with code from react-table v6